# Updating file content using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webassembly, sql.js

I'm building a frontend app using [wasm sqlite](https://sql.js.org/#/) I've the following code that is working very well:

```
const SQLpath = '/www/wasm/sql';
const sqlPromise = initSqlJs({
    locateFile: file => `${SQLpath}/sql-wasm.wasm`
  });
const dataPromise = fetch("http://localhost:8080/www/data/database.sqlite").then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
sqlRun();
async function sqlRun(){
  const [SQL, buf] = await Promise.all([sqlPromise, dataPromise])

  const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buf));

  // Run a query without reading the results
  db.run("CREATE TABLE test (col1, col2);");
  // Insert two rows: (1,111) and (2,222)
  db.run("INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?), (?,?)", [1,111,2,222]);

  // Prepare a statement
  const stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1 BETWEEN $start AND $end");
  stmt.getAsObject({$start:1, $end:1}); // {col1:1, col2:111}

  // Bind new values
  stmt.bind({$start:1, $end:2});
  while(stmt.step()) { //
    const row = stmt.getAsObject();
    console.log('Here is a row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
  }

  // Downloading the database.sqlite
  const data = db.export();
 // const buffer = new Buffer(data);
 // fs.writeFileSync("filename.sqlite", buffer);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const blob = new Blob([data]);
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = 'database.sqlite';                     //filename to download
  a.click();
}
```

The last block is `downloading` a copy of the latest `database.sqlite` but I need to update the original backend file, is there a way that I can update the original file that is located at `http://localhost:8080/www/data/database.sqlite`

My app structure is:

[image]

Comment: Is this a frontend app and try to update the backend file system?

Comment: @ikhvjs yes it is the frontend app

Comment: Please update your question to clarify it. What you want is to update a file system from backend by the forntend app, right?

Comment: What have you tried so far in your backend codes? I think you can just send a request to your backend with the blob you prepared in frontend. Then, use some file API to create or update a file in backend.

Comment: @ikhvjs I'm trying to get it done by frontend only, without a server.

Comment: So, what you try to do is update a file in a backend server without connecting to the server? How could this possible?